# Graphics Card Issue - No Display

Tags: boot, display, amd-radeon, graphics

I found out recently that the [Accelero Twin Turbo](http://www.arctic.ac/en/p/cooling/discontinued-products/vga/215/accelero-twin-turbo.html?L=1) vga cooler I used on my [Gigabyte HD4850 1GB (one of these)](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/list.aspx?s=43&p=52,53@53@53@53,62&v=2,2@8@6@1,8) stopped working, so i decided to remove it and buy a new one. However I haven't had the opportunity to buy a replacement so I removed the cooler and put the video card back into the computer without any cooling assembly at all.

I didn't touch anything else inside my tower and I always touch bare metal in order to avoid static discharges. Now, when I turn on my PC, the display shows the BIOS splash screen and then it goes black.  My monitor displays a default message as if there is nothing connected to it.

My speakers are on but I never hear the Windows 7 startup sound, so it does not appear to be booting to Windows at all. Before I decided to use the video card without a cooling assembly everything worked the way it was supposed to during startup. I would hear a beep from the motherboard and then it would start to boot. Even though I do not have a display the motherboard still beeps.

I tried to enter the BIOS with F2, it shows me a "starting setup" message, but then the screen goes black and nothing happens! I tried removing the graphics card and inserting it back once and nothing happened.

I do not have another graphics card to use.  I have torn down the entire system, replaced my existing motherboard with an old ASRock motherboard that has onboard video and I still get no display.  Is there something that I have to do?

Comment: One thing that confused me.  You said that after all this, you tried an ASRock mobo that had onboard graphics, and got nothing.  That would mean that the ASRock board is no good (unrelated to using your video card without cooling), or that one of the components that you used between both assemblies is no good... or that you just messed up something when you tore everything down and rebuilt it on the ASRock mobo.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "naked" you mean that you have removed the heatsink and fan assembly that was attached to the card and all you have is the exposed card and GPU without any cooler of any kind.

Chances are you now need to buy a new graphics card.

The cooler fitted to the card is there for a reason. Graphics cards typically run very hot and need a lot of active cooling to keep them cool and prevent overheating. Without the cooler/fan in place the GPU could very well overheat before any thermal throttling could occur and so cause permanent damage to the graphics processor.

Hopefully this has not damaged any other components in your system, it sounds like your power supply is fine and the motherboard in general could be okay. Windows is probably not starting up because either the graphics card has some minor functions working but not enough for a display so Windows is hanging on trying to communicate with the GPU.

Comment: ^ sounds like it for sure. weird how xapnsma indicated that the "VGA" portion of the card is still functioning. It might mean that they could boot into a VGAonly setup and survive for a while. With Win7 even the welcome screen stuff can go to a fuller resolution, leaving only seeing things like the bios and boot screens. For that Integrated grafics stuff, might need to switch a few things around to use it. turn it On in the bios, and set it as first item in the bios (PEG/PCI or VGA switch in there), and wire it to the monitor and all.

Comment: I was wondering about that myself and the only thing I can come up with is that the most basic graphics modes are handled by the graphics card BIOS and any higher modes need the main GPU.

Comment: yes by naked i mean that i have removed the heatsink and fan assembly. however i found out that my cooler has stopped working for some time now. this means that my pc worked with no active cooling for at least a month! i know that even without the fans working there at least some passive cooling through the heatsink below the fan assembly. removing the cooler entirely can cause the card to overheat in 2 seconds? I know that ati can hold up to 100+ degrees celcius. do you think finding and inserting the old passive cooling heatsink solve this problem??? (thank for replying anyway :) )

Comment: @xapnsma A heatsink without a working fan still provides passive cooling via the heatsink. NO heatsink offers NO cooling.

Comment: The heatsink alone will provide a large amount of passive cooling depending on the mass of metal and surface area of the fins which provide a way for heat to escape. No heatsink means that all the generated heat is focused on the surface of the GPU.  Replacing the heatsink at least may allow the GPU to stay cool enough, but the damage may have been done already.